# Got Ph.D Degree from India on the basis of Ph.D Comprehensive Exam + Ph.D Thesis now thinking of doing Course Work in another university

Tags: coursework

I applied for a teaching job. I was told by the selection committee that I didn't do coursework in my Ph.D program.
I replied that the university Ph.D program requires two years of Independent Study on the courses specified by the course Advisor and then a comprehensive Exam and then Thesis Adjuducation.

What can I do if the university has no provision for registration of formal courses ?

I have asked them to consider the Credits of Courses that I have in two Masters Degrees ( 42 Credit Hours from Master of Engineering + 41 Credit Hours from MS )

When I had checked the qualifications of one of the Selection Committee members, he did one MS (with 24 Credits Course Work + 30 Credits Course work in Ph.D with thesis in both the programs)

I am thinking of Joining again Ph.D PROGRAM in a university where there is coursework, and complete 30 Credit Hours of Course Work.

Please advise how can I do this ?

Comment: _What can I do if the university has no provision for registration of formal courses?_ — Don't expect to get a teaching job afterwards. — _I am thinking of Joining again Ph.D PROGRAM in a university_ — Since you already have a PhD, getting admitted to another PhD program in the same field will be extremely difficult.

Comment: @JeffE, Just out of interest, why would it be hard to get admitted to another PhD programme in the same field if one already has another PhD?

Comment: @phiri Many universities (like mine) will not award duplicate degrees, as a matter of policy. So if you have a master's degree in math, for example, you cannot be admitted to the master's program in math.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to take a big step of re-doing a PhD just based on this one interview you had, then I'd recommend reconsidering the thought. Have you received similar responses in the past? If yes, then may be the university that awarded you a PhD, doesn't has a good reputation. In that case too, a second PhD is not the best option. You can think of some Post doctoral certification or Post-doc research work. That would enhance your profile and would not count as a repetition.

Comment: Greetings Sir. After award of PhD, in an interview for a job in a Saudi University, I was asked for my PhD transcript that had only one course and commented that I did not have enough coursework credits like a US PhD. Coursework in North American system is counted beyond the Bachelor degree. In fact, I did my Masters from same university where I was interviewed, with GPA (3.804/4.00). All professors of that university have PhDs from US. I was upset. I have already earned 42 credits after PhD degree. Now my problem is how to add coursework credits earned to an already awarded PhD's transcript.